# Easy way to break lines in tabular

Tags: tables, line-breaking

is there a quick and painless way to auto-breaklines in Latex?

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{id} & nome dashboard & creator~ & tipo & URL                                                                               \\ 
\hline
1                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
2                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
3                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
4                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
5                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
6                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring  \\
7                      & user field     & creator  & type & longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried almost everything.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please advise if the strings in the final column would happen to be URL strings.

Comment: Yeah they are actually url, does it make that difference? Thanks.

Comment: Yes -- Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which doesn't line-break the URL strings automatically, but which is nevertheless quick and painless: Load the `xurl` package and encase the URL strings in `\url{...}` wrappers.

I would also like suggest loading the `tabularx` package and replacing the `tabular` environment with a full-widty `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,xurl,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\urlstyle{same} % optional
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} r lll X @{}}
id & nome dashboard & creator & tipo & URL \\ 
\midrule
1 & user field & creator & type & \url{longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring} \\
2 & user field & creator & type & \url{longstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstringlongstring}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, you really saved me.